# How to get http request for date value and char value in ServletRequest

Tags: spring, hibernate, servlets

I make a web using spring-hibernate,
I want to update a table that the primary key is a Date and one of the field is a char,
but I got problem to get http request for value of date and char,

this is my code;

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/updateKSEI.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateKSEI(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{

    Date WORKING_DATE = request.getDateHeader("WORKING_DATE");
    UpdateKSEI updateksei = updatekseiService.get(WORKING_DATE);

    String SISTEM = updateksei.getSISTEM();
    String DESCRIPTION = updateksei.getDESCRIPTION();
    char FLAG = updateksei.getFLAG();

    updateksei.setWORKING_DATE(WORKING_DATE);
    updateksei.setSISTEM(SISTEM);
    updateksei.setDESCRIPTIOM(DESCRIPTION);
    updateksei.setFLAG("Y");
    updatekseiService.update(updateksei);
    model.addAttribute("successUpdate", true);
    return listKSEI;
}
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @developerwjk I got red warning ~

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is the only problem with your code.  But there is an error that will prevent it from even compiling.  Look at the [docs for HttpServletRequest.getDateHeader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getDateHeader%28java.lang.String%29). That function returns a `long` not a `Date`.  So you need to use a constructor, not just assign the long into a `Date` object.

```
long dlong = request.getDateHeader("WORKING_DATE");
if(dlong != -1)
{
    Date WORKING_DATE = new Date(dlong);
}
```